# How to add a CSS class to its parent when an input(transparent) got focus?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the 'checker' component in bootstrap. The HTML of a checker is:

```
<div class='checker'>
   <span>
      <input type='checkbox'/>         <--- the Opacity of this checkbox is 0
   </span>
</div>
```

I want to show the focus outline when the input got focus, however, the Opacity of the input is 0.

Is there any way to add a CSS class to it's parent when it has focus?
Or any other way to show the focus outline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class to the parent `span` with JavaScript. Here is a CodePen example using jQuery: http://codepen.io/pzi/pen/YPyWQq

Also, don't forget to use a `label` element (as you can see in my example).